# Excel 2007 - automatically fill down a row with date range matching a specific pattern

Tags: microsoft-excel-2007

I have an excel sheet for leave schedule. In Row 1 for example is a merged cell with the month name Jan and in  row D3 and E3 are group of date 01-05 and 08-12 and so on.

[image]

How can I do this?

Comment: @Dave (and @pnuts): I agree that the question is hard (impossible?) to understand as it stands.  My point is that not everybody has access to a file server where he can publish files that are visible to the world (or they do not know where to find such a server).

Comment: sorry if i made everybody confused but how can i attach my sample data. Here is what i wanted to do: I have a leave planner for the staff but instead of doing the highlighting manually i wanted to do it automatically as i enter the start date and the end date. My Calendar is group into a weekday example January 2012 01 -05 and so on.Ex. Start date-15 Jan End Date 30 Jan so it should automatically highlight 15-19 up to 29-31. I hope this is clear enough. Thanks-DatuElijah

Answer (score 1):

It is ugly because I think there is probably a better way to achieve the result you want but to answer your question:

1. Ensure `Row2` is formatted as Text and `ColumnB` and `ColumnC` as Date.
2. Select `D3`.
3. **Styles**, **Conditional Formatting**, **New Rule**, **Use a formula to determine which cells to format**.
4. Copy

`=OR(AND(DAY($B3)=VALUE(RIGHT(D$2,2)),DAY($B3)>=VALUE(LEFT(D$2,2))),AND(DAY($C3)>=VALUE(LEFT(D$2,2)),DAY($C3)<=VALUE(RIGHT(D$2,2))))`

2. Paste into **Edit the rule Description**.
3. **Format values where this formula is true:**.
4. [Set Format as required] Click `OK`.
5. Enter `=$D:$H` into **Applies to** and click `Apply`, `OK`.

You should achieve something like the following:

[image: SU478913 example]

where I have shown the result of placing the conditional formula into `D3` and copying across & down. This is not required however but serves as a check if the formatting is not what you expected.

Should work for all of `ColumnD:H`.

I have included the formula in the image as that layout may help in understanding the logic.

Comment: Sorry got busy at work. Thanks that is what i want but there is one detail that needs to be fix. i was trying to fix it but i run out of time, what if the leave is more that 30 days? lets say 10 jan 2012 up to 31 jan 2012, it will only fill the 08-12 and 29-31 but 15-19 and 22-26 there is no fill. Sorry to bother you again.- thanks in advance

Comment: actually i already have the daily one done for next year but my  new boss wants it in that grouping because that was done previously by my ex-boss and for him its much easier to easy the date of leave and i am just trying to look if theres way to do it that way by just the conditional formatting or even a macro. Just the same thank you so much for the time you have spend in helping me. If there is really no way to do it automatically i will just going justify the daily schedule i have made. Thanks so much for the help....Datu Elijah